# Does "commit_failure_policy: ignore" Cassandra option allow to write data if fail occur?

Tags: cassandra

Could anyone clarify what happened when "commit_failure_policy" is set to "ignore" and one of the commit files is damaged during writing of data? Does the system create new commit file and continue writing there or all the upcoming writes fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this documentation the answer is that it will let all incoming writes fail:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html

Comment: Yes, I read this documentation before asking but it confused me a little bit. Does this mean that reads will be available and all writes will result to errors?

Comment: Thank you, bechbd!